# JMeter WebDriver Sampler: Convert JavaScript to Groovy script

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, performance-testing

I have a WebDriver Sampler which works perfect with JavaScript. I need to convert this into Groovy.

```java
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)

var user = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('loginUserName'))
user.sendKeys(['adminstafftest1'])

var pass = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('loginPassword'))
pass.sendKeys(['STuser1225'])

var login = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('loginSubmit'))
login.click()
```

Groovy script:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

def user = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id('loginUserName'));
user.sendKeys(['adminstafftest1']);

def pass = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id('loginPassword'));
pass.sendKeys(['STuser1225']);

def login = WDS.browser.findElement(By.id('loginSubmit'));
login.click();
```

However, this throws an error:

> javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
> at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158)
> at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source)
> at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:101)

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [JavaDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) for the [Selenium API](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html) version you're using and see what parameter(s) does the function you're trying to use accepts.

As far as I can see [WebElement.sendKeys()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...)) function expects to get a [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and for some reason you're passing an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to it.

So if you change this line:

```
 user.sendKeys(['adminstafftest1'])
```

to this one:

```
user.sendKeys('adminstafftest1')
```

your code should start working normally.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)